# Django: How to order by calculated field using float precision?

Tags: django, floating-point, sql-order-by, precision

I have a model like this:

```
class Program(models.Model):
votes_sum = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, default=0)
voters_counter = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, default=0)
...
```

And I get the 10 best rated programs:

`best_rated = Program.objects.filter(Q(creator__profile__type = 'us') & ~Q(voters_counter = 0)).extra(select={ 'total' : 'votes_sum / voters_counter' }).extra(order_by=['-total'])[:10]`

But, I need to use float precision! Because a Program with 3.75 points must be before Program with 3.25 points. 
I've tried:

`.extra(select={ 'total' : 'float(votes_sum) / float(voters_counter)' })`

But this syntax is not possible!

Any help? Please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you sending the 'order_by' parameter to a second extra()? Also you should try investigating the actual SQL query string being formed.

Comment: Using extra() is the only way that I know to order by calculated fields. There is another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best_rated = Program.objects.filter(Q(creator_*profile*_type = 'us') & ~Q(voters_counter = 0)).extra(select={ 'total' : '1.0 * votes_sum / voters_counter' })